# multiple file view like DB-view

Tags: linux, bash, solaris

Is it possible, using bash, to create a view/virtual file that when opened combines 2 files into 1?

example:

```
FILE_META_1.txt
FILE_META_2.txt
```

combines into

```
FILE_META.txt
```

Comment: `cat FILE_META_1.txt FILE_META_2.txt > FILE_META.txt`?

Answer (score 0):

In general, this is not possible. I assume you mean you want to logically link 2 files without creating a 3rd file that is the sum of the 2 files. I've often wanted this feature also. It would have to be done at the kernel level or via a special file system, maybe use FUSE. [UnionFS](http://www.fsl.cs.sunysb.edu/project-unionfs.html) provides this for directories, but not for files. [FuseFile](https://github.com/vi/fusefile) looks like it does what you want. Also take a look at the [Logic File System](http://padator.org/wiki/wiki-LFS/doku.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can open them stream-like wise with process substitution:

```
cat <(cat FILE_META_1.txt; cat FILE_META_2.txt;)
```

`<(*)` here expands to a named pipe path which you could open and access like a file for input.